# Console changes color for no apparent reason when I use the CHAR_INFO structure

Tags: c++, windows, colors, console, background-color

I'm pretty new to c++ and computer programming in general and I am trying to make a racing game on the console for a University project. I'm currently trying to understand how to use windows.h and screen buffers and I'm following an online tutorial. This is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <ctime>
#define WIDTH 80
#define FIELD_W 70
#define HEIGHT 35
using namespace std;

HANDLE whdl;
HANDLE rhdl;
int main() {
    srand(time(0));

    SMALL_RECT window_size = { 0, 0, WIDTH-1, HEIGHT-1 };

    whdl = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    rhdl = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);

    SetConsoleTitle(L"---RAGE RACER---");

    SetConsoleWindowInfo(whdl, TRUE, &window_size);
    COORD buffer_size = { WIDTH, HEIGHT };
    SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(whdl, buffer_size);

    COORD CharacterBufferSize = { WIDTH, HEIGHT };
    COORD CharacterPosition = { 0, 0 };
    SMALL_RECT console_write_area = { 0, 0, WIDTH-1, HEIGHT-1 };
    CHAR_INFO buffer[WIDTH * HEIGHT];

    for (int y = 0; y < HEIGHT; ++y) {
            buffer[WIDTH * y + 1].Char.AsciiChar = (unsigned char)99;
            for (int x = 1; x < FIELD_W; ++x) {
                buffer[x].Char.AsciiChar = ' ';
            }
            buffer[WIDTH * y].Char.AsciiChar = (unsigned char)99;
        }

        WriteConsoleOutput(whdl, buffer, CharacterBufferSize, CharacterPosition, &console_write_area);

        getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I am aware that the for loop is off, the problem is that whenever I run the code the console is covered in red spaces, if I try to run another program it works fine and if I press keys they are written white on black as always. I am using Visual Studio 2019. Thank you in advance and sorry for the obscenities I may have written without realising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`buffer` is initially uninitialized, containing random garbage. You initialize `Char` member of its elements, but not `Attributes` member, which is still random garbage at the time `WriteConsoleOutput` is called. And `Attributes` is what determines character color.

Formally, your program exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing uninitialized objects.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! May I ask how would you to initialize it?

Comment: Initialize it to zero at least, if you don't need specific colors.